# How can I know in Java application if my UNIX OS have a GUI layer, or it's command-line only?

Tags: java, user-interface, unix, javafx, layer

I have a Java application, using ***JavaFX*** for **GUI**. This application does not run on Unix server without a GUI layer, e.g. ***X-Windows***.

Can I know, from Java application, whether or not the Unix OS on the machine includes a GUI layer?

Comment: `java.awt.headless`

Comment: Never did that but how about checking the `DISPLAY` environment variable existence? Don't know if it's just a Linux or Unix default var.

Comment: `new ProcessBuilder("xdpyinfo").inheritIO().start().waitFor() == 0`?

Comment: @VGR what does it mean when it's equal to 0? that it _Started_ or _Stopped_?

Comment: It has been a standard for decades that a process exits with an exit value of zero when it succeeds, and nonzero to indicate failure.  If `xdpyinfo` succeeds, you have an X-Windows display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was added as a comment by @VGR:

```
return new ProcessBuilder("xdpyinfo").inheritIO().start().waitFor() == 0 ;
```

When 0 (successful) then there's ***X-WINDOWS*** display, otherwise, there's not.